# ArithmeticException divide by zero occasionally

Tags: java, android

I have a JAVA(running on Android) method which occasionally catching ArithmeticException due to divide by zero, although the variable inSampleSize is set to 1 before the loop and only getting multiplied by 2 every time. Below is the method as is. Any idea what am I missing here ? Thanks!

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    try {
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        LogUtil.Log("ArithmeticException=" + e.getMessage() + " inSampleSize=" + inSampleSize);
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        inSampleSize=1;
    }
    LogUtil.Log("inSampleSize="+inSampleSize);
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: What gets logged when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Divide by zero. Logging inSampleSize says it is indeed ZERO. Can't see the reason for that ...

Comment: Have you ever realized what was wrong? I'm having the same issue and it's hard to explain

Answer (score 3):

At first sight, it looks like if you initialize a number to `1` and only ever multiply it by `2`, you can never get a result of `0`. However, after 32 iterations of the `while` loop, the value of `inSampleSize` will in fact be `0`. This is caused by the fact that Java ignores the overflow of `int`.

This can be demonstrated by executing the following code:

```
int count = 0;
int inSampleSize = 1;
while (inSampleSize != 0) {
 count++;
 inSampleSize *= 2;
}
```

This loop will terminate when the value of `inSampleSize` is zero, at which point `count` is 32.

So, the remaining question is under what circumstances does the above code perform 32 iterations of the `while` loop? The answer is, when both `reqWidth` and `reqHeight` are less than `1`.

So, for example, if you called:

```
calculateInSampleSize(options, 0, 0);
```

you would see the issue you're describing.

If `reqWidth` or `reqHeight` are zero, it probably doesn't make sense to load a bitmap at all as it won't be visible. However, maybe you're getting the width and height using `View.getWidth()` and `View.getHeight()` and under some circumstances that's being called too early, before the views are laid out at which point those methods might return 0. Obviously this last bit is a guess and impossible to know without seeing more of the code, but I'm confident that if you added `reqWidth` and `reqHeight` to your logging, you'd see they're less than 1 when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Because height and halfHeight are int you face this exception.

```
final int halfHeight = height / 2;
```

if height = 1 halfHeight will be 0 here. In while when you call

```
halfHeight / inSampleSize
```

you will get ArithmeticException because halfHeight is 0.

**Solution** : convert all measures in double or BigDecimal before you start your operations, especially when you have divide operation.